# Adding elements inserted by user to the list

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Hallo i'm trying to add elements to list but i couldn't know why the elements (UserName & Salary) not adding to the list,
i tried a lot but i couldn't know what i'm missing here..!

Thanks

```
class emp():
empCount=0


count = 0
while (count < 3):
    def __init__(self,name=input('entername:'),Salary=input('Enter Employee Salary: ')):
        empList = []
        self.name=name
        empList.append(name)

        self.Salary=Salary
        empList.append(self.Salary)

        emp.empCount = +1

    #def Emp_Salary(self):
        print ('Name:', self.name, 'Salary:', self.Salary)

        print ('total Employee %d' % emp.empCount)

        print empList
    count = count + 1
```

Comment: What is your error message

Comment: my friend i'm calling the function and its shows me to add but when its printing the list, it's just shows me the last element i add not all of them, like that

  entername:'a'
  Enter Employee Salary: 1
  entername:'b'
  Enter Employee Salary: 2
  entername:'c'
  Enter Employee Salary: 3
  ('Name:', 'c', 'Salary:', 3)
  total Employee 1
  ['c', 3]
  ('Name:', 'c', 'Salary:', 3)
  total Employee 1
  ['c', 3]

Comment: (1) Please show where you are calling the function. (2) Fix your indentation because this code is not syntactically valid. (3) You should still not be defining the function in a loop like this.

Comment: Okay thanks i got your points. but may you please tell me the general idea how can i add elements in a list throw function because i was trying a lot and i got nothing, and this is my old Code before i modify on it

Comment: And one more a question in your opinion i shouldn't put  input(..) , if not where it's should be !!

Comment: @Anas, my answer shows how to add elements to a list

Comment: @Anas (1) Don't dump code into comments. Edit your question. (2) You would say `def A(self, name, Salary): ...` and later `a.A(input(...), input(...))`. That is how functions are used. Then the `a.A(...)` call should be the part inside a `while`, not the `def`. Please go back to some tutorials on functions and go through them more slowly, completing simple exercises as you go. I promise you need it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will take your advise and thanks for it :)

Answer (score 2):

Move `empList = []` out of `while`.

---

As you mentioned in the comments under your question, you'd like to add elements to a list, here is an example.

```
list_employ = []

for i in range(3):
    name = input('Entername: '),
    salary = input('Enter Employee Salary: ')

    list_employ.append([name, salary])

print(list_employ)
```

A test,

```
$ python stackoverflow.py 
Entername: 'a'
Enter Employee Salary: 1
Entername: 'b'
Enter Employee Salary: 2
Entername: 'c'
Enter Employee Salary: 3
[['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3]]
```

Comment: Moving out of while might not have been it, but I do think the strange structure with the while outside the function definition was a part of it.

Comment: Thanks a lot that's was helpful

Comment: @XamuelDvorak, since the questioner didn't express clearly, I have to guess:-(. Acutrally, he/she'd like to know how to add elements to a list.

Comment: i'm sorry my friend if i didn't express the question very well. but i looking for the idea not the solution and exactly to know what i'm missing nothing more :)

Comment: Then in that case `append` is your answer.

Comment: @Anas, your code is not right indentation. `IndentationError: expected an indented block`

Answer (score 0):

## thanks guys

## The Solution is:

```
class emp():
empList = []
  def A(self,name,Salary):

    self.name=name
    self.Salary=Salary

    print ('Name:', name, 'Salary:', Salary)


 for x in range(3):
  a=emp()
  a.A(input('enter Name'),input('Enter Salary'))
  a.empList.append([a.name,a.Salary])
  x +=1

print (emp.empList)
```

## Thes output:

```
enter Name'a'
Enter Salary1
('Name:', 'a', 'Salary:', 1)
enter Name'b'
Enter Salary2
('Name:', 'b', 'Salary:', 2)
enter Name'c'
Enter Salary3
('Name:', 'c', 'Salary:', 3)
[['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3]]
```